# JavaScript regex to get separated matches between two phrases

Tags: javascript, regex

What is a regex pattern I can use to parse the following text:

```
Mission m1
"Mission a is completing exam"
End Mission
Something is not necessary
Task t1
"Task b is keeping house"
comment: "... End Task"
End Task
abc
Task t2
Do something
End Task
```

.. so that it looks like the following :

```
[1]:
Mission m1
"Mission a is completing exam"
End Mission

[2]:
Task t2
Do something
End Task

[3]:
Task t2
Do something
End Task
```

I tried this regex pattern `\b(?:Mission|Task)\b(.|\n)*\b(?:Mission|Task)\b` - the problem is that it only returns one result containing both of three parts.

Comment: use `split` function.

Comment: Split with double newline: `s.split("\n\n")`. Or use `s.split(/^(?=Task|Mission)/m)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete rewrite of the previous answer because your input is quite different from what you showed in the beginning.

You need a simple regex matching a string between two strings:

```
/^(Mission|Task)\b[\s\S]*?^End \1$/mg
```

Here is an [unrolled version](https://regex101.com/r/qkziS7/3) of the same regex:

```
/^(Mission|Task)\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!End \1).*)*\r?\nEnd \1$/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qkziS7/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(Mission|Task)\b` - either `Mission` or `Task` whole words
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the first...
- `^End \1$` - `End`, space and the word captured into Group 1, as a whole line.

Comment: Well! I intend to find out blocks of text having structure "Mission...End Mission" or "Task...End Task". And there are some unnecessary strings outside blocks that do not match to results.

Comment: I have checked your new input and updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems OK, though probably `(^|\n)(Mission|Task)` is enough for your needs (Find all lines starting with 'Mission' or 'Task'. The reason is I don't think your end goal needs to match the entire paragraph - see below). Your main problem is probably that you don't use a [global modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp):

```
pattern=/(^|\n)(Mission|Task)/g;
```

Another problem is (I think) you're XYing this. I think the above regex and `replace` would be easier here, but since you want a different replacement for each match you can't just use [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp):

```
yourText.replace(pattern,constantString)
```

You can work around this using a function and a global var:

```
var index = 1;
yourText.replace(pattern,function(x){ return "P"+(index++)+"\n"+x;})
```

Note the `/g` will cause replace to work on all matches in string. If you still want to use your pattern just add `/g`.

**EDIT**
forgot to post the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gja62uff/).